# Usage of an Internal R Package Error Message

Tags: r, package

I am trying to use a company internal r-package and I am getting the following warning message in R-Studio when I want to load the library. So installation works, but when I try to load the library is spits this error:
"In fun(libname, pkgname) :"

Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide more details (a reproducible example, preferably).

Comment: So there is this internal package. Which can be downloaded from github. Once I downloaded the package I try to load it with library("packagename"). It does load the package but there is the warning message ""In fun(libname, pkgname) :". And it seems like the package is loaded by when I try to use functions out of this package it does not work. It spits the error that the used package has not been loaded. (Even though it was)

Answer (score 1):

try installing first with `install.packages("path to your .zip package file", repos=NULL)`
Then use `library` or `require`. If anything goes wrong with these two steps, there is a problem with the package itself and you should ask its developers for help.
EDIT: if your package is on github, you can try:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools")
devtools::install_github("your package URL")
```